# How do I make a 2 decimal answer with this simple code?

Tags: javascript, java, double, currency

```
public class TaskFive {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      int cheques=5;
      double baseFee=10.0; 
      double bankCharge,costCheque;

      if (cheques<20){

         costCheque=0.1; // 

      }else if ((cheques>20) && (cheques<39)) {

         costCheque=0.08;

      }else if ((cheques>40) && (cheques<59)) {

         costCheque=.06;

      }else{

         costCheque=0.04;

      }

      bankCharge=baseFee+(costCheque*cheques); //dont mind this… just a catch my lecturer added

      System.out.println("____________________________________________"+"\nBank Charge:P"+bankCharge+"\t Base Fee:P"+baseFee+"\n Cost of a Cheque:P"+costCheque+"\t Number of Cheques:"+cheques+"\n____________________________________________");

   }
}
```

Result here is 10.5 and 10.0 when I need 10.50 and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(bankCharge)`

It will convert it to 2 digits after decimal